# Validating Arrays of radio buttons in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, radio-button

I am using Laravel 5.1 and homestead.

My issue is when validation fails, the radio buttons do not repopulate with data from the original user's input.

My validation rules from PostRequest.php

```
public function rules()
    {
        //validating input text field --> this one works
        $rules = ['owner' => 'required|max:15',];

        //validating array of input text fields --> this too works
        foreach($this->request->get('item') as $a => $z)
        {
            $rules['item.'.$a] = 'required';
        }

        //validating array of radio buttons --> does not return with data
        foreach($this->request->get('radio') as $b => $y)
        {
            $rules['radio.'.$b] = 'required';
        }


        return $rules;
    }
```

A segment of my view(blade.php)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="tcell col-xs-6">
        <label for="item[0]" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="item[0]" name="item[0]" type="text" placeholder="enter item" value="{ { old('item.0') } }"/>
    </div>
    <div class="tcell col-xs-6">
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="s15" name="radio[0]" value="5" /><label for="s15" title="5">5</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s14" name="radio[0]" value="4" /><label for="s14" title="4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s13" name="radio[0]" value="3" /><label for="s13" title="3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s12" name="radio[0]" value="2" /><label for="s12" title="2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s11" name="radio[0]" value="1" /><label for="s11" title="1">1</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 ...

    <div class="tcell col-xs-6">
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="s20" name="radio[1]" value="5" /><label for="s20" title="5">5</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s19" name="radio[1]" value="4" /><label for="s19" title="4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s18" name="radio[1]" value="3" /><label for="s18" title="3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s17" name="radio[1]" value="2" /><label for="s17" title="2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="s16" name="radio[1]" value="1" /><label for="s16" title="1">1</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The old() function worked for both input(text) and array of input(text). but I do not know how to apply it with radio buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the  solution

```
<input type="radio" id="s15" name="radio[1]" value="5"  { { old('radio.1')=="5" ? 'checked='.'"'.'checked'.'"' : '' } } /><label for="s15" title="5">5</label>
<input type="radio" id="s14" name="radio[1]" value="5"  { { old('radio.1')=="4" ? 'checked='.'"'.'checked'.'"' : '' } } /><label for="s14" title="4">4</label>
...
```

This will only help redirect back with the inputed data, however, validation will still fail if nothing is selected since nothing gets submitted. The fix is to use `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop. You must get the count of the radio buttons to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

try to amend as following

### blade template:

```
<div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="s15" name="radio" value="5" /><label for="s15" title="5">5</label>
        <input type="radio" id="s14" name="radio" value="4" /><label for="s14" title="4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" id="s13" name="radio" value="3" /><label for="s13" title="3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="s12" name="radio" value="2" /><label for="s12" title="2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="s11" name="radio" value="1" /><label for="s11" title="1">1</label>
    </div>
```

---

### Form request

```
public function rules()
{
    //validating input text field --> this one works
    $rules = ['owner' => 'required|max:15', 'radio' => 'required'];


    //validating array of input text fields --> this too works
    foreach($this->request->get('item') as $a => $z)
    {
        $rules['item.'.$a] = 'required';
    }



    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post particularly the view(blade) part since it was only showing one set of radio buttons. It should show arrays of radio buttons. My validation actually works but my main issue is the inputed data is not redirected back when validation fails. I thinking I have to use the old() function but I do not know how to do it with radio button

Comment: great that you could handle it. would you mind update your post with solution in case others have same issue, please?